# Rendering a partial with different content blocks on the same page: i need a partial helper that accepts a content block

Tags: ruby, haml, erb, padrino, middleman

I really like how Sass mixins let you wrap a block of code with a **customizable** wrapper:

```
=container($class)
  .#{$class}.container
    .container-inner
      @content

+container(header)
  foo: bar

+container(main)
  baz: quux
```

Resulting CSS:

```
.header.container .container-inner {
  foo: bar;
}

.main.container .container-inner {
  baz: quux;
}
```

I'm trying to do the same with Padrino/Middleman partials. The problem is that partials not accept content blocks (whyyy?). :(

I tried to work it around by passing content blocks into `content_for`, but subsequent uses of `content_for` would append to content rather than replace it:

Partial `partials/container.haml`:

```
.container
  = yield_content :container
```

Page `index.html.haml`:

```
- content_for :container do
  Foo

= partial('partials/container')


- content_for :container do
  Bar

= partial('partials/container')
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  Foo
</div>
<div class="container">
  Foo
  Bar
</div>
```

As you can see, it duplicates my content which is absolutely unacceptable. Also, this way does not allow to provide arguments that would be used to customize wrapper HTML.

So i thought of creating a helper. It would enable the following usage style which is **way more elegant** than `content_for` and also **supports passing variables into content block**:

```
= partial_with_content_block('partials/container', class: 'header') do
  Foo

= partial_with_content_block('partials/container', class: 'main') do
  Bar
```

How do i implement such a helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, but I left the partial out:

```
def container(options={}, &block)
  raise ArgumentError, "Missing block" unless block_given?
  content = capture_html(&block)
  content_tag(:div, content, options)
end
```

Call as:

```
= container(class: 'main') do
  p More content here
```

But now that I think if it, this could be all handled with default Padrino methods:

```
= content_tag :div, class: 'main' do
  p More content
```

Comment: Good point, I was too quick assuming this was Rails. But it seems that Middleman has a `content_tag` method that you can use. `block_given?` is a plain Ruby method, so I think this will work in Middleman. Edit: except for [`capture`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture)...

Comment: Thank you @zwippie, i had failed to notice the `content_tag` method. My container wrapper consists of two wrapping elements, so your helper example is very helpful. I've edited your answer to be fully Padrino/Middleman compliant.

Comment: You're welcome. I never knew that the Padrino/Middleman view layer took so much goodness of Rails (did they?). Looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Middleman partials do accept content blocks, but the syntax is slightly different. ERB is given below, but you should be able to do this in HAML, as well.

```
<% partial 'my_partial' do %>
    My Content
<% end %>
```

### my_partial.html.erb

```
<p>
    <%= yield %>
</p>
```

### Result

```
<p>
    My Content
</p>
```

Comment: I originally said you must use `render_partial`, but that isn't true. `render_partial` is just an alias for `partial`, so either will work.